# How to get unique data as per dictionary key in python

Tags: python

```
  [
    {'id': 589, 'series': 17, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 590, 'series': 17, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 584, 'series': 18, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 585, 'series': 18, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 597, 'series': 18, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 598, 'series': 18, 'job_id': 19193},
    {'id': 584, 'series': 19, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 585, 'series': 19, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 598, 'series': 19, 'job_id': 19193},
    {'id': 584, 'series': 20, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 585, 'series': 20, 'job_id': 19103}
  ]
```

expected output

```
  [
    {'id': 590, 'series': 17, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 597, 'series': 18, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 584, 'series': 19, 'job_id': 19103},
    {'id': 584, 'series': 20, 'job_id': 19103},
  ]
```

How can i get unique data as per series in this python dictionary??

Comment: What do you consider *unique* data here? Please provide *expected output*?

Comment: i have edited the question.

Comment: So you retain the *last* (?) element per value for *series*?

Comment: i want unique as per series

Comment: but which row do you want to retain? The first, the last, it does not matter?

Comment: series row.. which is at the middle

Comment: I'm a little confused by the input/output. You have a list of dictionaries? The square brackets denote this is all one list.

Comment: when you are chosing unique values say for `series 18` why do you want `597` over `598` is there a reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce you unique dictionaries but it is not clear which `id` you want from each one there was no mention of how you are determining that secondary selection

```
d2 = {i['series']: i for i in d}
d3 = list(d2.values())
```

> ```
> [{'id': 590, 'series': 17, 'job_id': 19103}, {'id': 598, 'series': 18,
> 'job_id': 19193}, {'id': 598, 'series': 19, 'job_id': 19193}, {'id':
> 585, 'series': 20, 'job_id': 19103}]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list and add to an empty list each first item found.

To check if the value has found before, compare current item from iteration against the founds list.

```
uniq = []
found = []

for item in list_of_dictionaries:
    if item['series'] not in found:
        found.append(item['series'])
        uniq.append(item)

print(uniq)
```

Some points to attention on this approach:

- It is ignoring the other data (keys).
- It is getting the first occurrence found of list.